# Mediatek MT7921K WIFI fails on 23.10

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I tried two different Mediatek MT7921 cards.
According to Linux-hardware it is apparently working flawlessly with "recent kernels" (of November 2022)
https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:14c3-0608-14c3-0608

I see the wifi adapter in network-manager, but clicking on any SSID removes the device for a few seconds.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep -i mt79`

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you- your comments helped me look where I needed.
looking at the journalctl I spotted: (IP redacted)

```
generate[7210]: nm-device: NM-110a73d2-ecb7-4218-9219-e2eafff55b81: the renderer for nm-devices must be NetworkManager, it will be u>
NetworkManager[7210]: /etc/netplan/90-NM-1f51d085-3509-45d4-82e9-d0aac667f33b.yaml:13:19: Error in network definition: invalid endpo>
NetworkManager[7210]:       - endpoint: "XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX:51820"
NetworkManager[7210]:                   ^
NetworkManager[5408]: <error> [1699429602.7463] BUG: the profile cannot be stored in keyfile format without becoming unusable: canno>
NetworkManager[5408]: **
NetworkManager[5408]: nm:ERROR:src/core/settings/plugins/keyfile/nms-keyfile-writer.c:551:<unknown-fcn>: assertion failed: (<dropped>
NetworkManager[5408]: Bail out! nm:ERROR:src/core/settings/plugins/keyfile/nms-keyfile-writer.c:551:<unknown-fcn>: assertion failed:>
systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Consumed 1.552s CPU time.
```

About the time of adding this wifi adapter, I changed my IP address , and entered xx:xx:xx:xx:port   , using : instead of .

this was done in NM GUI, which is apparently not sanity checking it.
Once I corrected it, things work as expected.